# How to underline text in verbatim environment?

Tags: formatting, verbatim

Am I missing something, or is it simply not possible to underline text within a verbatim environment?

```
\begin{verbatim}
  I want to underline the following word: word
\end{verbatim}
```

I guess I could ask the same question with regard to bold or italic print, but in those cases I can see that this is not what you can do with an ordinary typewriter. But any typewriter has an underscore and I can use it to underscore text. Can the verbatim environment not do that?

Comment: verbatim isn't designed to emulate a typewriter so much as literally show the input source. So you could of course do another line with `     ------` but if you want a typeset underline you need to escape back out of verbatim, possible with verbatim but easier to use the listings package which has a built in mechanism to allow escapes to TeX commands such as `\underline` or of course simply `\texttt{I want to underline the following word: \underline{word}}`

Comment: Is it just text you need to typeset, or will it be special characters like `\\``, `$`, `&`, etc.?

Comment: This sounds like you want formatting of keywords? It could be done using the [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listinhgs) package

Comment: The aim is to typeset examples from transcripts that were transcribed according to the Jeffersson notation (http://www.liso.ucsb.edu/liso_archives/Jefferson/Transcript.pdf) or similar notations. Or rather, a simplified version, which does not include special characters but unterlining. The point is that these transcripts already exist as pdfs so that copying and pasting them into a verbatim environment seems like the easiest option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apart from the suggestions made in the comments, you might also consider `fancyvrb`.  For example, you can write something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=+\[\]]
    The +underline[quick brown fox] jumped over the lazy dog.
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This did the job, thanks. However, it's not an ideal solution since I need quite a lot of characters to underline a single word (or even letter). So if anyone has a more efficient solution (someting like: `The _quick brown fox_ jumped over the lazy dog`), please post it!

Comment: @Christoph did you find any efficient solution to this problem?

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39898/problem-with-underline-in-listings It uses the listings package, but that has functionality to enable this sort of markdown-esque formatting.